# pandas: what can be done with a .pipe() that can't be done with .apply(), on a GroupBy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

In the example from the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-pipe) about the new `.pipe()` method for GroupBy objects, an `.apply()` method accepting the same lambda would return the same results.

```
In [195]: import numpy as np

In [196]: n = 1000

In [197]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Store': np.random.choice(['Store_1', 'Store_2'], n),
   .....:                    'Product': np.random.choice(['Product_1', 'Product_2', 'Product_3'], n),
   .....:                    'Revenue': (np.random.random(n)*50+10).round(2),
   .....:                    'Quantity': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n)})

In [199]: (df.groupby(['Store', 'Product'])
   .....:    .pipe(lambda grp: grp.Revenue.sum()/grp.Quantity.sum())
   .....:    .unstack().round(2))

Out[199]: 
Product  Product_1  Product_2  Product_3
Store                                   
Store_1       6.93       6.82       7.15
Store_2       6.69       6.64       6.77
```

I can see how the `pipe` functionality differs from `apply` for DataFrame objects, but not for GroupBy objects. Does anyone have an explanation or examples of what can be done with `pipe` but not with `apply` for a GroupBy?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

What `pipe` does is to allow you to pass a callable with the expectation that the object that called `pipe` is the object that gets passed to the callable.

With `apply` we assume that the object that calls `apply` has subcomponents that will each get passed to the callable that was passed to `apply`.  In the context of a `groupby` the subcomponents are slices of the dataframe that called `groupby` where each slice is a dataframe itself.  This is analogous for a series `groupby`.

The main difference between what you can do with a `pipe` in a `groupby` context is that you have available to the callable the entire scope of the the `groupby` object.  For apply, you only know about the local slice.

**Setup**
Consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=list('XXXXYYYYYY'),
    B=range(10)
))

   A  B
0  X  0
1  X  1
2  X  2
3  X  3
4  Y  4
5  Y  5
6  Y  6
7  Y  7
8  Y  8
9  Y  9
```

**Example 1**
Make the entire `'B'` column sum to `1` while each sub-group sums to the same amount.  This requires that the calculation be aware of how many groups exist.  This is something we can't do with `apply` because `apply` wouldn't know how many groups exist.

```
s = df.groupby('A').B.pipe(lambda g: df.B / g.transform('sum') / g.ngroups)
s

0    0.000000
1    0.083333
2    0.166667
3    0.250000
4    0.051282
5    0.064103
6    0.076923
7    0.089744
8    0.102564
9    0.115385
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Note:

```
s.sum()

0.99999999999999989
```

And:

```
s.groupby(df.A).sum()

A
X    0.5
Y    0.5
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

---

**Example 2**
Subtract the mean of one group from the values of another.  Again, this can't be done with `apply` because `apply` doesn't know about other groups.

```
df.groupby('A').B.pipe(
    lambda g: (
        g.get_group('X') - g.get_group('Y').mean()
    ).append(
        g.get_group('Y') - g.get_group('X').mean()
    )
)

0   -6.5
1   -5.5
2   -4.5
3   -3.5
4    2.5
5    3.5
6    4.5
7    5.5
8    6.5
9    7.5
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but pipe always wins over apply also in the respect that pipe is using vectorizing under the hood while apply doesn't. This shortens the operation time significantly.

Answer (score -5):

```
print(df.groupby(['A'])['B'].apply(lambda l: l/l.sum()/df.A.nunique()))
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality), and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers.