# How do I compute cooccurrences of variable values within days over time to produce an adjacency list?

Tags: python, pandas

I am analyzing data from the GDELT database of news documents on Google Cloud.  The file contains a column for date, for one of 300 theme codes, and a frequency value.

Here is my data.  The sample data file has approximately 46,000 rows: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11oUiznvFTKGAOz1QXavbiWH1sxgCJHbFfysu0F0MdKs/edit?usp=sharing

There are 284 unique themes, listed here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gN3Vc5W6rGekF8P_Rp73BL2YaO6WTDVp-DpP0Il22vk/edit?usp=sharing

I need to, within each day, create pairs of themes, weighted by the product of their frequencies.  Then, I need to output an adjacency list of: theme_A, theme_B, and weight, to subsequently do network analysis on the themes over time.  I am stuck at the point of computing the theme cooccurrences.

```
#Import packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Read in data file
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\james\Desktop\Documents\Downloads\Cybersecurity\cybertime.csv')
df.head

#Create bigrams of themes by days, based on cooccurrences weighted by frequencies.
#Iterate rows until new date is found, then compute weighted cooccurrences.
#Weights are products of theme A frequency (freq) and theme B frequency.


#Output the adjacency list.
```

Comment: I think what yore looking for is groupBy

Comment: Thanks!  Once I do the groupby on date, how would I make all theme bigrams (weighted by the product of pair element frequency) for each date?

Comment: You file contains 1024 themes. How do you group them to obtain just 300?

Comment: There are 284 unique themes.

Comment: groupBy and then apply with a custom function to calculate the weight by frequency , df.groupby(['date', 'theme'])["frequency"].apply(lambda x : x.astype(int).sum()

Comment: Yes, the custom function is what I need help with  :)  Just learning python!

Comment: I added to the description a link to the theme codebook file.  It has the 284 unique themes.

Comment: What are you supposed to do with the lines containing themes not listed in the other file, like DRONES,  ECON_BITCOIN, ECON_BUDGET_DEFICIT, ... Just ignore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a custom function with groupBy and apply with pandas data frame. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374597/apply-function-to-pandas-groupby)

or do:

```
df.groupby(['date', 'theme'])['frequency'].apply(lambda x : x.astype(int).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks!  This nicely groups data by date and by theme.  But, how do I do the next step -- produce the cooccurrences, which for each date lists: theme_A theme_B cooccurrence frequency?  E.G.:  cooperate terror 61

Comment: E.G.:  cooperate terror 61 \n  cooperate intelligence 14 \n intelligence shortage 77, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can optionally filter out all rows from the initial csv file containing themes not contained in the GDELT-Global_Knowledge_Graph_CategoryList:

```
df = pd.read_csv('cybertime.csv')
gdelt = pd.read_csv('GDELT-Global_Knowledge_Graph_CategoryList.csv')
df.drop(df.loc[~df.theme.isin(gdelt.Name)].index, inplace=True)   # optional
```

Next, you could pivot your dataframe to get a matrix of 30 rows (one per day) and 194 columns (one per theme). If you do not filter you will get a 30x1028 dataframe.

From that point, you can do a matrix product of the transposed matrix by the original matrix: it will give you a 194x194 matrix containing the sums of the products of the frequencies of pair of events (same as above 1028x1028 if unfiltered)

You have just to unpivot (`melt`) that matrix to get your adjacency list.

Code could be:

```
df2 = df.pivot(index='date', columns='theme', values='freq').fillna(0)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(df2.values) @ df2.values,
                   index=df2.columns, columns = df2.columns)

df4 = df3.rename_axis('theme_A').reset_index().melt(
    id_vars=['theme_A'], var_name='theme_B', value_name='weight')
```