# How to sum values under GroupBy and consecutive date conditions?

Tags: pandas, date, pandas-groupby, shift, cumsum

Given table:

| ID | LINE | SITE | DATE | UNITS | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | AAA | 02-May-2017 | 12 | 30 |
| 2 | X | AAA | 03-May-2017 | 10 | 22 |
| 3 | X | AAA | 04-May-2017 | 22 | 40 |
| 4 | Z | AAA | 20-MAY-2017 | 15 | 44 |
| 5 | Z | AAA | 21-May-2017 | 8 | 30 |
| 6 | Z | BBB | 22-May-2017 | 10 | 32 |
| 7 | Z | BBB | 23-May-2017 | 25 | 52 |
| 8 | K | CCC | 02-Jun-2017 | 6 | 22 |
| 9 | K | CCC | 03-Jun-2017 | 4 | 33 |
| 10 | K | CCC | 12-Aug-2017 | 11 | 44 |
| 11 | K | CCC | 13-Aug-2017 | 19 | 40 |
| 12 | K | CCC | 14-Aug-2017 | 30 | 40 |

for each row if ID,LINE ,SITE equal to previous row (day) need to calculate as below (last day) and (last 3 days ) :
Note that is need to insure date are consecutive under "groupby" of ID,LINE ,SITE columns

| ID | LINE | SITE | DATE | UNITS | TOTAL | Last day | Last 3 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | AAA | 02-May-2017 | 12 | 30 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | X | AAA | 03-May-2017 | 10 | 22 | 12/30 | 12/30 |
| 3 | X | AAA | 04-May-2017 | 22 | 40 | 10/22 | (10+12)/(30+22) |
| 4 | Z | AAA | 20-MAY-2017 | 15 | 44 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | Z | AAA | 21-May-2017 | 8 | 30 | 15/44 | 15/44 |
| 6 | Z | BBB | 22-May-2017 | 10 | 32 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | Z | BBB | 23-May-2017 | 25 | 52 | 10/32 | 10/32 |
| 8 | K | CCC | 02-Jun-2017 | 6 | 22 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | K | CCC | 03-Jun-2017 | 4 | 33 | 6/22 | 6/22 |
| 10 | K | CCC | 12-Aug-2017 | 11 | 44 | 4/33 | 0 |
| 11 | K | CCC | 13-Aug-2017 | 19 | 40 | 11/44 | (11/44) |
| 12 | K | CCC | 14-Aug-2017 | 30 | 40 | 19/40 | (11+19/44+40) |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this cases i usually do a for loop with groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#copied your table
table = pd.read_csv('/home/fm/Desktop/stackover.csv')
table.set_index('ID', inplace = True)
table[['Last day','Last 3 days']] = np.nan

for i,r in table.groupby(['LINE' ,'SITE']):
    #First subset non sequential dates
    limits_interval = pd.to_datetime(r['DATE']).diff() != '1 days'
    #First element is a false positive, as its impossible to calculate past days from first day
    limits_interval.iloc[0]=False

    ids_subset = r.index[limits_interval].to_list()
    ids_subset.append(r.index[-1]+1) #to consider all values
    id_start = 0

    for id_end in ids_subset:    
        r_sub = r.loc[id_start:id_end-1, :].copy()
        id_start = id_end 

        #move all values one day off, if the database is as in your example (1 line per day) wont have problems
        r_shifted = r_sub.shift(1)

        r_sub['Last day']=r_shifted['UNITS']/r_shifted['TOTAL']

        aux_units_cumsum = r_shifted['UNITS'].cumsum()
        aux_total_cumsum = r_shifted['TOTAL'].cumsum()

        r_sub['Last 3 days'] = aux_units_cumsum/aux_total_cumsum

        r_sub.fillna(0, inplace = True)

        table.loc[r_sub.index,:]=r_sub.copy()
```

You can make a function and apply in groupby, it would be cleaner: [Apply function to pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374597/apply-function-to-pandas-groupby). It would be more elegant.
Wish I could help you, good luck

Comment: Hi ,  thank you so much . it work good . the problem is (as you mentioned ) day are not consecutive to all groups.  in the example i gave(updated) , if you look at "LINE=K, SITE=CCC etc" dates has gaps .

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. 
OBS:
-The diff() function applied to datetime objects returns '1 day' if days are consecutive. 
-I need to append r.index[-1]+1 to consider all lines, the +1 compensates the -1 in r_sub assignment
-the .copy() method avoid pandas to return a view

Comment: One more thing... how do i extend this case to 7 day or 'n' days back ? The idea is look back for 3,7, n days and do the calcs'  even if there are gaps of day or two within 7 days for example.

Comment: i think rolling and timedelta might solve it but i am not sure how !?

Comment: limits_interval = pd.to_datetime(r['DATE']).diff() >n
n is the variable with n days. But iam not sure i understood your question.